# Problemas com o AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou a tentar apagar uma fotografia com o ajax.

Já consegui recolher os dados(localização da foto) e agora estava a tentar receber essa mesma localização com um outro ficheiro .php .

O que me esta a falhar é essa mesma "transferência". Penso fiz tudo bem, mas continuo a não conseguir receber os dados.

Este é o código

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( ".delete" ).click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var original_url = element.attr('original_place');
    var thumbnail_url = element.attr('thumbnail_place');

if (confirm('Tem a certeza?')){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'apagar_foto.php',
        data:{foto_original:original_url,foto_thumb:thumbnail_dir,},
        success: function()
        {
            alert('Eliminado');
        }       
    });
};
return false;
});
</script>
```

Como podem ver, guardo em 2 variáveis as localizações das fotos.

Após uma pequena confirmação faço o envio

Código que era suposto receber os dados

```
$foto_original = $_POST['foto_original'];
$foto_thumb = $_POST['foto_thumb'];

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$foto_original');</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$foto_thumb');</script>";
```

Conseguem-me dizer onde pode estar o erro? Desde já, perdão por esta pergunta simples, mas isto não me deixa já há algum tempo. Obrigado.

Comment: Podes verificar melhor o que sucede quando usas o ajax se incluires um parâmetro na função `success`. Observe os valores desse parâmetro nas ferramentas do navegador (a maioria os abre através de F12). Vês no retorno o texto passado ao `echo`?

Comment: @Renan A funcionalidade dos echos que tenho é simplesmente para informar-me que os dados foram recebidos.

Comment: O alert 'Eliminado' está executando? Os outros nunca vão executar, são scripts que você nunca inclui na página

Comment: @bfavaretto O alert não é executado, nem os dados são enviados. Os scripts (echos) estão noutro ficheiro .php, o tal: apagar_foto.php. E o objetivo deles é em "alertar" quando os dados chegam lá.

Comment: No arquivo PHP, faça `print_r($_POST)` e no retorno do AJAX, na função `success`, coloque: `success: function (data) { console.log(data); }`. Execute o código e veja se algum retorno é exibido no console da página.

Comment: Ok, apaguei o comentário anterior, já que tinha um gralha minha, perdão. O resultado é um array com duas linhas, que representam o conteúdo que quero enviar.

Comment: Então seu AJAX está enviando e recebendo os valores conforme esperado, assim como o PHP está recebendo. Basta desenvolver a lógica que deseja agora. Lembre-se que `alert` na página PHP nunca será exibido, pois esse código não será executado no navegador.

Comment: você pode colocar eval(data) para executar o echo do php como javascript dentro do success do ajax, ou seguir a dica do Anderson, que é a melhor. Para excluir o arquivo use: unlink('caminho')  http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unlink.php

Comment: Obrigado a todos, já resolvi o problema. Os dados afinal eram enviados, mas tinha ideia de que não, já que, não via os alerts. Obrigado mais uma vez :D